# “make” error while compiling TPlink wm722n driver

Tags: drivers, kali-linux

I have downloaded the Tplink wm722n V2 driver from the tplink website. when i tried to 'make' it give me a error...

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build M=/root/Desktop/kernel-master/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417-target-kernel_4.4  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I have also tried it with another driver from git.. https://github.com/mfruba/kernel/tree/master/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink

It also gave me the same error... i just noticed that there is no build directory in /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build (there is no build folder there)

Can anyone help me out please..

Comment: Start my fixing the given error. Check that the linux-headers package are installed for the kernel 4.9.0-kali3-686-pae. If yes, try `mkdir /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build`

Comment: i have installed the headers using  "apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-686-pae"  command.. do i also need to install "4.9.0-kali3-686-pae"  one?

Comment: when i try..  "apt install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae"   its give error...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae'

Comment: `apt-get update; apt-cache search linux-headers` should give you available linux-headers packages.

Comment: yeah i did that it says already installed...
... But when i tried to make again it gives... make
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build M=/root/tmp/rtl8188eu  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2